# Displaying the array from the controller as a table in the view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, database, html-table

In the controller, I receive the data from the database and then I assign the relevant list to the function that will run all the functions in this controller. This list returns to view here I will show the data in the table but ... is undefined error

now i will share with you my functions in controller

```
    public function table_backlog()
    {
        $dailyData=\DB::table('backlogs')->get()->toArray();
        //dd($dailyData);
        return ['dailyData'=>$dailyData];
    }
  protected function getAllBChart() {
        
        return view('deneme',[
            'table_backlog'=>$this->table_backlog()]);
    }
```

*View.blade:*

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <table class="table table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Incident No</th>
                    <th>Assignment Group</th>
                    <th>Open Group</th>
                    <th>Open Time</th>
                    <th>RN Short Name</th>
                    <th>Days</th>
                    <th>Brief Description</th>
                </tr>
            <thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach($dailyData as $key => $row)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $row->number }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->assignmentGroup }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->creatorGroup }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->opened }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->configuration }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->description }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   var dailyData={!! json_encode($table_backlog['dailyData']) !!}

</script>
```

This line assigns the data from the controller to the variable. When I check with DD I can see the data

```
var dailyData={!! json_encode($table_backlog['dailyData']) !!}
```

I tried this but I get undefined error. My for loop doesn't work either

Comment: You can't iterate over `$dailyData` since that PHP variable doesn't exist. Your JS variable is not relevant here (PHP and JS are two different things) and unless you're going to use the data in JS later, there's no reason to encode it as JSON and store it in a JS variable at all. Try `@foreach($table_backlog['dailyData'] as $key => $row)`.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Thank you for a quick and efficient reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this version coz error from array's key

```php
@foreach($table_backlog['dailyData'] as $key => $row) 
<tr> 
   <td>{{ $row['number']}}</td> 
   <td>{{ $row['assignmentGroup']}}</td> 
   <td>{{ $row['creatorGroup']}}</td> 
   <td>{{ $row['opened']}}</td> 
   <td>{{ $row['configuration']}}</td> 
   <td>{{ $row['description']}}</td> 
</tr> 
@endforeach
```